# asp.net checkboxlist without javascript

Tags: asp.net

My checkboxlist doesn't work when javascript is disabled.

Is there any workaround to make checkoboxlist to autopostback when javascript is disabled?

Comment: May I ask why you need this? Unless you have strict accessibility requirements or expect javascript to be disabled, it is not very likely for users to just turn it off.

Comment: I want to implement concept call progressive enhancement where the site will work without javascript and then add javascript to enhance it

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it is not possible to have autopostback working without javascript.

You could provide a traditional Submit button as a fallback and only make it visible when javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Autopostback only works if your javascript is enabled.

A workaround is to have a input button and make it appear within noscript tags

```
 <noscript>
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" OnClick="MyButton_OnClick" Text="Submit" />
</noscript>
```

Add your functionality to 'OnClick', button will only appear if the javascript is disabled

Answer (score 0):

afaik you need javascript for autopostback.

but you could do a workaround, instead of using checkboxes you could use many forms. but just do this if you really really need this "autopostback" feature.

with css you could change the icon for the button, you only have to check in the postback which state the "checkbox" has and set the correct css class.

cheers